# Sharing preferences between commandline and GUI programs

Tags: python, cocoa, macos, environment-variables

I am stymied by a seemingly simple problem. I have several preferences that I would like to access from a Cocoa app and a commandline python script.  The preferences are mostly locations to things on disk.  Since the locations build of each other ( $LOCA=$LOCB/stuff for example), using environment variables and something like .bash_rc would be ideal. The problem is that only commandline programs inherit variables from .bash_rc, Cocoa apps do not.

What is the best mechanism to store this stuff so that python scripts and Cocoa apps can access them alike?

thanks.

Comment: I *think* python can access many osx frameworks. If thats the case, and I think it is, just store it in a preference file and access them both that way.

Personally Im not a fan of applications storing preferences outside the normal means. it makes it harder for the end user to find things for such applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Python 2.6, the [`plistlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/plistlib.html) module is available in standard Python. You can use this to read and write `.plist` files (and use [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from Obj-C). Neither the `NSPropertyListSerialization` nor `plistlib` will perform the sorts of substitutions you want, so you will have to build this in to both the script and the OS X program.

**EDIT:** `plistlib` only reads and writes the XML-serialized `.plist` files, not the binary format -- use the `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0` constant in your Obj-C code when saving the `.plist`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could get the substation stuff for free. This is a livable compromise though. Thanks.